# Losing 3d visualization of DEM in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I am trying to see 3D of DEM using arcscene but when I change from no elevation value from surface to floating on surface dem disappear from screen does not appear even after clicking on zoom to layer?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What are the precise steps that you perform, from starting ArcScene, to observing this software behaviour?